# How to propose migration of an off-topic question that is poorly phrased for destination site?

Tags: discussion, migration, cross-posting

Suppose a new user posts a question on Foo.SE. I'm confident that it's *definitely* off-topic for Foo.SE, but I think it *might* be on-topic for Bar.SE. However, the question might not be currently phrased appropriately for Bar.SE, but it could be cleaned up to be suitable.

The question in particular is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/202566/51295 on Programmers.SE. I think it would be a good fit for WebApps.SE, but WA.SE has [the requirement that shopping questions be carefully phrased](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1003/31356):

> ...while you may think you need a recommendation, what you really need to show is that you've tried something with an existing service. Failing that, you're more than open to having suggestions for other ways to solve the problem...

The question is currently not phrased according to that standard, but it *could* be edited to fit. The OP has a clear objective requirement and has found a service that is not suitable, but the question happens to be phrased as "what service will let me do this?" instead of "can I do this with service X (or any service)?".

I could:

1. Flag for migration as-is and trust the WA.SE community to edit it into correct form.
2. Edit the question into shape -- possibly not exactly how the OP would phrase it, but up to WA.SE standard -- then flag a mod for migration.
3. Encourage the OP to delete the question and then re-post -- with corrected phrasing -- on WA.SE. This is can currently be done fairly cleanly since it has no answers, but may be messier in the general case.

Which option is most appropriate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not do option #1 of migrating and then fixing.  The idea of migration is not to burden the target site with significant cleanup of a question you migrate.  You should only be migrating great questions that will require minimal editing to be a good fit.

The second option is fine, assuming that you're capable of making the edits appropriately.  Sometimes the edits that would need to take place are radical enough that the OP would need to make them, or there is information that needs to be added that only the OP can provide.

For that we have the third option, which you should use if the second is not possible.  I would have your comment(s) focus on fixing the question up first though.  Only after the question is fixed up should you mention migration (otherwise, in my experience, it becomes too tempting for the OP to re-create their question on the target site without fixing it up first).  However, if you know that Bar.SE is likely a good target site, but aren't completely sure that it's appropriate or aren't sure exactly how the OP might need to fix the question up to be appropriate for that site, it may be appropriate to just mention Bar as a possible migration site.

Note that if you're able to help the OP fix the question up through comments you can still flag for migration; you don't *need* to have them delete and re-create.

Answer (score 7):

Number 2 if you're willing to do the work, number 3 otherwise.

Never number 1.

First rule of question migration: **Don't Migrate Crap**